# Android Studio: Use GPU

Tags: android, android-studio, gpu

I am working in Android Studio and using the emulator to test my app. Is there anyway that I can get the emulator to use the GPU for certain things?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you go to **AVD Manager** > Select your emulator from the list :

[image]

Click on the **Edit this AVD** button & click on **Show Advanced Settings** :

[image]

On the Graphics options, select Hardware instead of Software, and click finish

Comment: Thanks! However it is not allowing me to change the graphics option. Currently it is set to automatic and not giving me any other choices. Do you know why?

Comment: @Tyler_Le10 try to create a new emulator, and don't select any emulator with Google Play Services

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry to keep bothering you, but now that this uses the GPU for the emulator, will it use the GPU for the phone if I download my app for testing or will I have to do something else?